# React Strict Mode causing issues during development

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-strictmode

I have this Skip component to conditionally skip pages. I noticed that instead of skipping ONE page, it skips two pages! I suspected that it might be the Strict Mode running the UseEffect code twice. I turned the Strict Mode off and now the Skip behaves as it should, i.e. skipping just ONE page. Is this a bad practice to turn strict mode off? I was assuming it was meant to help development, but it really threw me off for a couple of hours trying to figure out what was wrong!

```
const Skip = () => {
  // nav is a Zustand store reference that holds the page state
  // Zustand state updates need to be run in useEffect otherwise console throws errors.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (nav.isNextClicked) {
      nav.nextPage();
    }
    if (nav.isBackClicked) {
      nav.prevPage();
    }
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default Skip;
```

Comment: That error is *absolutely* because of strict mode. Debatable whether turning it off is acceptable practice... but this does smell like one of the cases it's supposed to prevent. `useEffect` is not supposed to have side effects, is there any way you could move that logic higher in the component tree?

Comment: @SoZettaSho Thanks for the reply. I assumed that useEffect hook is specifically designed for handling side effects. Isn't it the primary purpose of useEffect to perform tasks that have side effects, such as this code? I woud love to know what I am doing wrong here though.

Comment: Apologies, "not supposed to have side effects" wasn't the right wording so much as that effects should generally be pure/idempotent. I can't seem to find the issue where the react devs explicitly state the motivation for strict mode running everything twice, but see https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#notifying-parent-components-about-state-changes

Comment: Can't say more without knowing the meaning of `nav.isNextClicked`, etc... but perhaps there's a way to keep which page should be shown in pure js, and/or calculate the next page to be shown based on the current page and nav state...?

Comment: looks like you are handling a user action in an effect? if so, move the logic to the event handler. [more](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)